# hydra, let all keys work but not allow insert (self-insert-command)

Tags: evil, hydra, dap

I am setting up hydra + dap.

Although dap-hydra is provided, it messes up keybinding often times.

Often, I forget the hydra window is open and type something and messes up typing.
Furthermore, when hydra window is not visible, it sometimes seems to catches input away. (maybe a bug)

I think it'd be better if I make the source code buffer read-only while the hydra window is open.

It would be worth considering to make it togglable, so that I keep the hydra window open but interchange between source-edit mode and debug mode (hydra key is used)

I was wondering if there is an available library I could use, (it looks like vim and evil mode does similar thing where you toggle between edit / control mode, but I don't want vim key binding)

Evil seems has the notion of states.
I guess I want two states,

- regular emacs states (for source editing and moving)

  - it seems like Emacs + Insert state combined in evil
- debug states (for stepping through, and no source editing)

  - this seems to be Emacs state (where you can only navagiate

So I need to bind two keys..

- regular emacs state: to get out of evil mode, or turn off read-only mode
- debug states: to enter into evil Emacs state, or turn on read-only mode

I wonder if there's a better way..